# Custom camera , video is not playing with Audio when i record video with back camera

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

i am trying to make custom camera its working pretty well but when i switch camera to back position video is recording but there is no sound and when i change to front its working pretty well here is my full code. i am just new at this camera stuff if anyone can help i really appreciate.

```
    ` func changeCamera(){

    guard let input = session!.inputs[0] as? AVCaptureDeviceInput else { return }

        // Begin new session configuration and defer commit
    session!.beginConfiguration()
       defer { session!.commitConfiguration() }
        // Create new capture device
        var newDevice: AVCaptureDevice?

        if input.device.position == .back {

            newDevice = cameraWithPosition(position: .front)

        }else{
            newDevice = cameraWithPosition(position: .back)

    }
```

// Create new capture input
            var deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!

```
        do {
            deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: newDevice!)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        //session!.removeInput(input)
    if let inputs = session!.inputs as? [AVCaptureDeviceInput] {
        for input in inputs {
            session!.removeInput(input)

        }
    }

            session!.addInput(deviceInput)
    }

    func cameraWithPosition(position: AVCaptureDevice.Position) -> AVCaptureDevice? {

     let deviceDescoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession.init(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera],                                                                             mediaType: AVMediaType.video,position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)
       for device in deviceDescoverySession.devices {
            if device.position == position {
                return device
            }
        }
   return nil
     }`
```